# Why are <uses-permission> needed in android? what is their intention?

Tags: android, permissions

Why exactly `uses-permission`

Ex :

```
<uses-permission>android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

is needed to access various modules of Android. How is it that just adding one single line that too by the same programmer who is coding it, is actually providing security? I am new to Android programming and this is looking funny. Kindly explain what is the exact use of quoting the `<uses-permission>`

Answer (score 2):

Google made a whole page to describe the concept. Go through it and you will know the reason.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

**EDIT:** In addition to above information. These required permissions are shown to the user at the time of installing the application. They are even visible at the google play store for each app. While most users don't see reqd permissions before installing, some might check them out and if its interfering with their privacy more than required they may not install it or even give bad reviews on play store. These are mentioned in AndroidManifest so Google doesn't have to go through all the scenarios to check what all services the application might request in future.

Comment: Thank you for the link, Though the information contained by the link was useful. It doesnt answer my question. Adding one line is giving me permission. So if you give me an apk i install it, and i dont know what permissions you have acquired, and what you can do with it. Atleast for the permission i stated above, it did not ask the user to grant thepermission for anything

Answer (score 0):

Whatever permissions you have added in `<uses-permission>` are actually used later at installation time of your application. User will be asked that this applications require following permissions: Access network states. And if user accepts, the application can be installed. Else application won't be installed.

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) for ore clarification.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the above permission to read the connectivity state. It did not ask me for any permission. Then who gave it the permissions?

Comment: Ok. So if installing is granting permission, all the permissions that i am granting is without my knowledge. SO is it the right thing to do?

Comment: no it asks when you install it.  That is when it requests you to accept permissions that you have programmed into the app

Comment: I have also noticed that it didn't ask for such permissions as ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE or INTERNET. And I am not sure for reason behind that. But try to add permission for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. It will definitely ask for that permission. I think that might have something to do with level of security.